QGIS plugin showing multiple messages in the message bar
I am adding some user feedback to a plugin.
I have followed the pyqgis developer cookbook to create a message as below.
self.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
messagelinktext = 'something is happening'
self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("", messagelinktext, Qgis.Warning, duration=10)

This works fine but I would like to show a sequence of messages and at the moment the various steps take a while to execute but only the last message is displayed once the operations have been completed.

You could use QTimer.singleShot to create  a one-time timer that triggers the pushMessage-call after a specified time (in ms):
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info", "first message", duration=5)
QTimer.singleShot(5100, lambda: iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info", "second message"))


It seems all I need to do is add in  "self.iface.mainWindow().repaint()" between my messages so the intermediate ones  display

You might also consider running your sequence of steps in a QgsTask to avoid blocking the UI while they are running.

@couteau , I found some documentation regarding that but didn't get very far, re-painting the mainWindow seems to work fine for now but I can see running as tasks in the background would be better.
